# Concatenate json array; issue when adding a unique key

Tags: python, arrays, json, web-scraping

I am scrapping a website full of JSON arrays. I'm trying to concatenate them and add a unique key to every array (see the code below):

For each iteration, the bot calls the function test and if I print get_text, I have this:

```
{"status":{"code":0,"message":"Ok","user":{"isBanned":false,"isNotConfirmed":false}},"payload":{"vat":0,"price":{"201":{"100":{"batchsize_id":60916,"quantity":100,"product_price":14.12,"shipment_price":8.98,"country_id":"DE"},"200":{"batchsize_id":60922,"quantity":200,"product_price":19.13,"shipment_price":9.06,"country_id":"DE"},"300":{"batchsize_id":60928,"quantity":300,"product_price":23.64,"shipment_price":9.14,"country_id":"DE"},"400":{"batchsize_id":60934,"quantity":400,"product_price":28.4,"shipment_price":9.23,"country_id":"DE"},"500":{"batchsize_id":60940,"quantity":500,"product_price":32.93,"shipment_price":9.32,"country_id":"DE"},"600":{"batchsize_id":60946,"quantity":600,"product_price":37.08,"shipment_price":9.4,"country_id":"DE"},"700":{"batchsize_id":60952,"quantity":700,"product_price":41,"shipment_price":9.48,"country_id":"DE"},"800":{"batchsize_id":60958,"quantity":800,"product_price":44.72,"shipment_price":9.63,"country_id":"DE"},"900":{"batchsize_id":60964,"quantity":900,"product_price":48.24,"shipment_price":9.71,"country_id":"DE"},"1000":{"batchsize_id":60970,"quantity":1000,"product_price":51.59,"shipment_price":9.79,"country_id":"DE"},"minDeliveryDays":5,"maxDeliveryDays":8}},"productionCountry":["DE"],"minDeliveryDays":5,"maxDeliveryDays":8},"pager":{"total":null,"count":null,"current":1}}
```

And my code below try to concatenate every iteration and add a unique key for each array.

```
def test(url_final):
        get_url = requests.get(url_final)
        #get_dict = json.loads(get_url.text)
        get_text = get_url.text
        print(get_text)
        dictionary['a' + str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]] = get_text
        print(dictionary)

printit()
```

My only issue, is that "print dictionary" returns me this:

```
{'a6a465b1a': '{"status":{"code":0,"message":"Ok","user":{"isBanned":false,"isNotConfirmed":false}},"payload":{"vat":0,"price":{"201":{"100":{"batchsize_id":60916,"quantity":100,"product_price":14.12,"shipment_price":8.98,"country_id":"DE"},"200":{"batchsize_id":60922,"quantity":200,"product_price":19.13,"shipment_price":9.06,"country_id":"DE"},"300":{"batchsize_id":60928,"quantity":300,"product_price":23.64,"shipment_price":9.14,"country_id":"DE"},"400":{"batchsize_id":60934,"quantity":400,"product_price":28.4,"shipment_price":9.23,"country_id":"DE"},"500":{"batchsize_id":60940,"quantity":500,"product_price":32.93,"shipment_price":9.32,"country_id":"DE"},"600":{"batchsize_id":60946,"quantity":600,"product_price":37.08,"shipment_price":9.4,"country_id":"DE"},"700":{"batchsize_id":60952,"quantity":700,"product_price":41,"shipment_price":9.48,"country_id":"DE"},"800":{"batchsize_id":60958,"quantity":800,"product_price":44.72,"shipment_price":9.63,"country_id":"DE"},"900":{"batchsize_id":60964,"quantity":900,"product_price":48.24,"shipment_price":9.71,"country_id":"DE"},"1000":{"batchsize_id":60970,"quantity":1000,"product_price":51.59,"shipment_price":9.79,"country_id":"DE"},"minDeliveryDays":5,"maxDeliveryDays":8}},"productionCountry":["DE"],"minDeliveryDays":5,"maxDeliveryDays":8},"pager":{"total":null,"count":null,"current":1}}'}
```

How do I remove the string in front of each array?

Comment: Why is that output a problem? How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: What is your actual question? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the JSON back as a string rather than as a dictionary like you expect. In order to convert from a string into some values, it has to be parsed. You have the right call there, just in the wrong place. Once you have `get_text` populated (you might want to consider better names), you need to run `json_values = json.loads(get_text)`. Now `json_values` will contain the dictionary you expect, and you can assign it instead of `get_text`.

Comment: Thanks! But now I have a new issue. The Json has changed, {'aa0f2fb7b': {'payload': {'minDeliveryDays': 5.... }}} It should start by status, why is that? I don't get it?